# QString::compare() vs converting QString to numbers and then comparing

Tags: c++, qt

Is it faster to compare 2 `QString`s containing numbers, or to convert those `QString`s to numbers and then compare the numbers?

so which is faster?

```
QString str1,str2;
if(str1.compare(str2)==0)
```

OR

```
QString str1,str2;
if(QString::number(str1)==QString::number(str2))
```

The reason I'm asking is because I have to fill a `QMap` with error codes and error messages corresponding to those error codes. I'll be reading the error code / error message from an ini file, so I'm wondering whether it's better to convert the error codes to integers and have `QMap<int,QString>` or to just keep them as `QString`s and have `QMap<QString,QString>`. Which approach will give me the most optimal code?

Where the `QMap` contains `<error code, error message>`

Comment: Before you're downvoted edit your post to add some info as to what you've observed performance-wise with these two constructs. Also, whenever you're wondering about things, it is usually a good idea to look up the documentation (for algorithmic complexity) and the associated header files (for hints to implementation details).

Comment: QString str1; QString::number(str1) is incorrect. It is function that you use to convert number to QString. To convert QString to number use str1.toInt() or str1.toDouble() etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

String comparison is likely to end with trouble: "1.00" != "1.0" != "1" != "0001"

Always use numeric types for comparing numbers, and don't worry about imagined performance issues of such a minuscule piece of any whole.

Answer (score 0):

For a one time use just comparing the string will (probably) be faster than converting them to numbers and comparing the numbers.

If you need the result as a number for other steps then convert them to numbers at the start and store numbers.

If you error codes are contiguous then you would typically but them into a vector  indexed by `[error_code - first_error_code]`

BUT before doing any optimisation - 1, measure 2, decide if you care

Answer (score 0):

In the case of the code you've written, doing two conversions and comparing the results is going to be slower than comparing the strings directly.

The thing is, to do a string comparison, you must at worst visit each character of each string. In the != case, you may visit fewer characters before finding the diff and exiting the compare (I assume a compare routine that exits early on fail). In the convert and compare case, you MUST visit all characters of both strings, every time. So the direct compare case will be faster.

In the case of the maps, you'll want to use QString because you'll do the conversion once and do the compare many, many times. That means that the cost of the conversion will be swamped by the savings from the comparisons and you'll win in the end.

Answer (score 0):

With `QString` keys, the map is performing string comparisons on every insertion, deletion and lookup. Since those comparisons are done repeatedly, it's cheaper to convert the string to an integer before using it as a map key. Such a conversion then is only done once per item, and perhaps once per lookup the key for your lookup is originally in QString form as well.